# How to optimally distribute marked appearances of a word across the lines of a file?

Tags: algorithm

I have a text file with a story, where each sentence appears on a different line, e.g.:

```
ONCE UPON A TIME, THERE WAS A MOUSE NAMED ED.
ED WAS A FRIENDLY MOUSE.
HE HAD MANY FRIENDS.
HE LIVED IN A SMALL HOUSE WITH HIS OTHER MOUSE FRIENDS.
HIS MOUSE FRIENDS WERE FRIENDLY.
HIS FRIENDS LIVED IN A SMALL HOUSE.
...
```

I also created a word list, listing every word appearing in the story.

```
ONCE
UPON
A
TIME
...
```

This has about 6,000 sentences, 4,000 unique words.

I need to find an algorithm, which I will write into a BASH script, which optimally fits this criteria:

1. Each of the words in the word list is marked exactly one time with braces in the story, e.g.:

   {ONCE} {UPON} {A} {TIME}, {THERE} {WAS} A {MOUSE} {NAMED} {ED}.
   ED WAS A {FRIENDLY} MOUSE.
   {HE} {HAD} {MANY} {FRIENDS}.
   HE {LIVED} {IN} A {SMALL} {HOUSE} {WITH} {HIS} {OTHER} MOUSE FRIENDS.
   HIS MOUSE FRIENDS {WERE} FRIENDLY.
   HIS FRIENDS LIVED IN A SMALL HOUSE.
   ...

Any of the locations a word is found could be potentially marked, such as the first occurrence, 3rd occurrence, last occurrence, etc.

2. After the script is run and all words are marked, lines without braces will be deleted. In the example above, "HIS FRIENDS LIVED IN A SMALL HOUSE." has not braces, so that line would be deleted.

Some algorithms will lead to many lines being deleted. Other algorithms will lead to fewer lines deleted.

3. The optimal algorithm is one which deletes the fewest lines. In other words, the selection of marked words needs to be optimally spread across multiple lines.

These are the algorithms I tried:

1. Marking the first occurrence of each word in the story. This resulted in ~50% of the lines being deleted, mostly at the end.
2. Marking the first occurrence of each word in the story appearing on a line that did not already have a brace. If no such line could be found, then the first occurrence of the that word in the story was marked. This resulted in ~25% of the lines being deleted.
3. Randomly marking words. The results are probably still often not optimal.

How can I create an algorithm which marks one occurrence of a word in a file, resulting in the broadest possible distribution of those marks across each of the lines, resulting in the fewest possible mark-less lines?

Answer (score 1):

Prepare a bipartite graph where the vertices of one part correspond to lines and the vertices of the other part correspond to words. Put edges wherever a word appears in a line. Find a [maximum matching](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matching_%28graph_theory%29#In_unweighted_bipartite_graphs) with, e.g., Hopcroft--Karp. For each line matched with a word, put braces around the occurrence of that word in that line. Do something ad hoc with the unmatched words.